# Multiple forms using same AJAX call with different outcomes?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

If I have many forms generated by PHP and want a "Reply" button on each of them, where it sends the content of the form via ajax to another php page, then can I use the same javascript snippet for all of these elements?

```
<form id="foo">
    <label for="bar">A bar</label>
    <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Reply" />
</form>
```

So if I do something like the following, then can I still handle all the responses individually and display the response ONLY on the element that "Reply" was clicked on?

```
$("#foo").submit(function(event){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/form.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData,
        // callback handler that will be called on success
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // log a message to the console
            console.log("Hooray, it worked only in the element it was clicked in!");
        });
    // prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: Yes you can, what problems are you having? The code you posted will only work for the form with id _#foo_

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking?  You're generating an HTML page with lots of `<form>` elements, and then wanting to handle the submission of a specific form, and maybe just show the result next to the form that was submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle all forms on the page, your code could work with minor changes.

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/form.php",
        type: "post",
        // You have to have a way to retrieve the form data
        data: getFormData(form),
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log("Hooray, it worked only in the element it was clicked in!");
        });
    // prevent default posting of form or just return false
    event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: OP said that he wanted to limit submissions to only click events

Comment: @Landon No, OP said he wanted to handle it only for the form that the button was clicked, not only if it was clicked.

Answer (score -1):

No, there are multiple ways on submitting a form.  You would want to change your first line to:

`$("#replybutton").click(function(event){`

Then you have to add that replybutton id to your button, and you'd have to explicitly list out the data elements in your ajax call.  Also, the `event.preventDefault()` would be unnecessary.  Come to think about it the whole `<form>` tags would be unnecessary as well.

There are other ways to do this using the form, but this is the simplest.

Comment: Can't tell why you would change from the submit handler to the click handler if you understand that there are multiple ways of submitting a form.

Comment: He said he wanted to limit the event that makes the ajax call to a click on the reply button, he wants to prevent those other ways of submitting the form

Comment: You misunderstood what the OP said, they said "display the response ONLY on the element that "Reply" was clicked on?" That means, apply just to the form that was submitted (clicked) not others.